# T SQL Question: How to apply changes to similar rows based on one row's value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

In my SQL Server 2008 DB, I have a table with records sort of like this:

```
ID 1 | Group1 | \ftp\path\group1\file1.txt
ID 2 | Group1 | C:\local\file\path\group1\file1.txt
ID 3 | Group1 | C:\local\file\path\group1\file1.txt
ID 4 | Group1 | C:\local\file\path\group1\file1.txt
ID 5 | Group2 | \ftp\path\group2\file1.txt
ID 6 | Group2 | C:\local\file\path\group2\file1.txt
ID 7 | Group2 | C:\local\file\path\group2\file1.txt
```

I need to update the table to look like this:

```
ID 1 | Group1 | \ftp\path\group1\file1.txt
ID 2 | Group1 | \ftp\path\group1\file1.txt
ID 3 | Group1 | \ftp\path\group1\file1.txt
ID 4 | Group1 | \ftp\path\group1\file1.txt
ID 5 | Group2 | \ftp\path\group2\file1.txt
ID 6 | Group2 | \ftp\path\group2\file1.txt
ID 7 | Group2 | \ftp\path\group2\file1.txt
```

I just don't know how to start this.  It's easy for me to find the values in the third column, because they match this wildcard: %:\%.

So, I'm trying to replace the value in those fields that match that wildcard with the correct value in a record that does not match that wildcard.  Damn, it's so hard to explain it.

I'm probably doing a poor job of explaining this issue but the right words are eluding me at the moment.

Any ideas?  I appreciate the help.

Comment: For clarification, I modified the example data to better highlight the values that I'm looking for with the wildcard search (%:\%) where the "invalid" values could be c:\ through z:\.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
UPDATE table
SET table.valueColumn = CT.correctValueColumn
FROM table as CT
    INNER JOIN table as IT on IT.group = CT.group AND CT.valueColumn LIKE '%:\%'
WHERE IT.valueColumn NOT LIKE '%:\%'
```

I don't have management studio on this machine so I'm not sure it's syntatically correct.

Hope this helps some.

Comment: I think you meant AND not &&. Probably want both LIKEs in the WHERE clause, since they're arguably filters, not join conditions.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: I disagree about the join. Basically, I would very probably do the same. The syntax is wrong indeed, though, as well as the `UPDATE table` bit (I think it should be `UPDATE IT` to avoid ambiguity.) The idea behind this join is to link the subset of `table` where the value is `LIKE '%:\%'` to the supplementary subset of all the other rows (those where the value is not `LIKE '%:\%'`). The latter is then updated based on the former. It seems very much like what the OP is after.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: I agree that it's somewhat subtle and open to different interpretations. In my opinion, either the two filters or the two alias declarations should trade places. Both filters define the subsets that are being joined, therefore they should be placed accordingly to the placements of the respective tables: if the table is in the FROM clause, its filter should be in the WHERE clause, and if the table is in the JOIN clause then its filter belongs in the ON clause where the join condition is. I'm not saying that it should always be so, I'm talking specifically about this case.

Comment: I takes a big man to admit his mistakes and I will pretend to be that person. Sorry, your join is correct. I just read it again, performancewise this also seems to be the best solution. Correct the other places and I change my minus to a plus. UPDATE t
SET t.valueColumn = ct.ValueColumn
FROM table t
INNER JOIN table ct 
on t.group = ct.group 
and ct.valueColumn LIKE '%:\%'
WHERE t.valueColumn NOT LIKE '%:\%'

Comment: This works with a few changes as suggested above and swapping ct and t.  --- UPDATE ct SET ct.valueColumn = t.ValueColumn FROM table t INNER JOIN table ct ON t.group = ct.group AND ct.valueColumn LIKE '%:\%' WHERE t.valueColumn NOT LIKE '%:\%'  --- MUCH THANKS TO ALL!

Comment: I was attempting to make the join faster by limiting the resulting set it needed it work on. That's why I did't put that part in the where. It wasn't syntactically correct as I called out but I edited it to be after reading the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

This gets the results you show, but I don't think the rules I applied match the way you described how you got here. You're talking about a wildcard '%:\%' but I see nothing in any of the data that looks anything like that.

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE
(
    ID VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Group] VARCHAR(32), 
    Val VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT @foo SELECT   'ID 1','Group1','Value 1'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'ID 2','Group1','Value 2'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'ID 3','Group1','Value 3'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'ID 4','Group1','Value 4'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'ID 5','Group2','A Different Value 1'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'ID 6','Group2','A Different Value 2'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'ID 7','Group2','A Different Value 3';

SELECT ID, [Group], Val FROM @foo;

WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ID, [Group], Val, 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY val)
    FROM @foo
)
UPDATE x
    SET x.Val = y.Val
    FROM x 
    INNER JOIN x AS y
    ON x.[Group] = y.[Group]
    WHERE y.rn = 1 AND x.rn > 1;

SELECT ID, [Group], Val FROM @foo;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at it based on my nearly useless problem description. ;)  I should have noted that the actual values for the third column would look like: c:\blah and z:\blah, etc.  In other words, the "correct" value would not contain a value that matches the wildcard %:\% and would thus need to be overwritten with the correct value in the one row that does not match the wildcard.  Does that explain it any better?